# Integrate $\int \cos x\cos^5(\sin x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I set $u$ to $\sin x, du$ to $\cos x$, then had $\cos^5udu$, then replaced $(\cos^2u)^2$ with $(1-\sin^2u)^2$ to get $\cos u(1-\sin^2u)^2$, then set $w$ to $\sin u$ and $dw$ to $\cos u$ and got $(1-w^2)^2dw$ then integrated to get $w- 2/3w + w^5/5$ then plugged back in $\sin u$ into the $w$'s and $\sin x$ into the $u$'s to get: $\sin(\sin(x)) - 2/3\sin^3(\sin(x)) + \sin^5(\sin(x))/5$... but wolfram alpha says $5/8\sin(\sin(x))+5/48\sin(3 \sin(x))+1/80\sin(5\sin(x))$ ... I think I'm leaving out a step.

Comment: You left out the $+C$. The rest is fine. Alpha for mysterious reasons decided to put it in a different form.

Comment: oh.. well thats a relief! sorta..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You left out the $+C$. The rest is fine. On to the next question!

Wolfram Alpha seems to have been programmed to prefer linear combinations of $\sin kx$ and $\cos kx$. Because of the endless trigonometic identities, integrals of trigonometric functions can be given in various ways, sometimes not obviously equivalent.